# C++ capture move initialized is const?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I am trying to move a local variable into the capture of lambda.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

// Moveable but not copyable object.
class WorkUnit
{
    public:
        WorkUnit(int)                               {}
        WorkUnit(WorkUnit&&)            noexcept    {}
        WorkUnit& operator=(WorkUnit&&) noexcept    {return *this;}
        WorkUnit(WorkUnit const&)                   = delete;
        WorkUnit& operator=(WorkUnit const&)        = delete;

        // Non const function.
        void doWork()
        {
            std::cerr << "Work\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    WorkUnit    data(4);

    // Use C++14 generalized lambda capture.
    std::thread test([data{std::move(data)}]()
        {
            // here it is complaining the `data` is a const value.
            // Is there a way to capture this as a non const?
            data.doWork();
        }
    );
    test.join();
}
```

When I compile I get this.

```
> g++ -std=c++14 WU.cpp
Test.cpp:26:13: error: member function 'doWork' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const WorkUnit',
      but function is not marked const
            data.doWork();
            ^~~~
```

I was expecting the captured value to be none const.

Comment: Put `mutable` after `[data = std::move(data)]() /*here*/ {`

Comment: Or capture it by reference: `[&data]() {
data.doWork(); }`.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Why the initializer is not allowed here?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Isn't it allowed as _init-capture_? Actually there is no reference to such an initialization in the standard, while it uses a `x = std::move(x)` like statement as an example, but I ever guessed it was allowed.

Comment: now I think it is allowed

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use [mutable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation):

> **mutable**   -   allows body to modify the parameters captured by copy, and to call their non-const member functions
>
> Unless the keyword `mutable` was used in the lambda-expression, the
>   function-call operator is const-qualified and the objects that were
>   captured by copy are non-modifiable from inside this `operator()`.

```
std::thread test([data{std::move(data)}]() mutable
    {
        // the function-call operator is not const-qualified;
        // then data is modifiable now
        data.doWork();
    }
);
```

It's worth noting that this allows to modify on the object captured by copy, which has nothing to do with the original object.

Comment: That allows the copy to be mutable, doesn't modify original.